# Group by where at least one group meets condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table Data with values:

Data:

```
id | name    | isrequired | isreleased
1  | test    | 0          | 1
1  | data    | 0          | 0
1  | another | 0          | 0
2  | test    | 0          | 0
2  | nan     | 0          | 0
3  | haha    | 0          | 0
4  | hehe    | 1          | 0
4  | jajaj   | 0          | 0
```

I am trying to return the group which has at least combination of `isrequired` and `isreleased` set to 1 (like at least one of `isrequired` or `isreleased` should be 1 in row). In this case, the query should return:

Expected output:

```
1 | test    | 0 | 1
1 | data    | 0 | 0
1 | another | 0 | 0
4 | hehe    | 1 | 0
4 | jajaj   | 0 | 0
```

Current query is:

```
select id, name, isrequired, isreleased
from testtable t
group by id, name, isrequired, isreleased
having count(*) > 0 and 
count(case when IsReleased = 0 and Isrequired = 0 then 0 else 1 end) >= 1)
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IsReleased] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsRequired] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Insert SQL:

```
insert into testtable
values
(1, 'test', 0, 1),
(1, 'data', 0, 0),
(1, 'another', 0, 0),
(2, 'test', 0, 0),
(2, 'nan', 0, 0),
(3, 'haha', 0, 0),
(4, 'hehe', 1, 0),
(4, 'jajaj', 0, 0);
```

Just a bit lost as to what to add next, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a windowed sum function for this:

```
with cte as (
    select *
        , sum(convert(int, IsReleased) + convert(int, IsRequired))
            over (partition by id) IsIncluded
    from testtable
)
select *
from cte
where IsIncluded > 0;
```